# How to create different groups in metro apps as shown?

Tags: html, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have created two groups as shown below for both groups i have image and some data below the image. But for the second group i don't want to show any image i want to display only user data. If i make any change in second group it's effecting both the groups which i don't want to happen. I'm not able to write different logic's for different groups. Can anyone help me providing some samples for solving this issue? I hope my question is clear.

Thank you.

here is my image which shows sample demo of my requirement

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a custom renderer function which can then select the template to use based on the contents of the data. Then, instead of referencing the DOM element that defines your template, reference the custom renderer function instead.

Take a look at the [ListView Item Template Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-item-templates-7d74826f/sourcecode?fileId=50887&pathId=1418094029) for information on how to build a custom renderer function.